# Flowable subcribe gets empty list after inserting records

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-mvvm

I am retrieving data from `Room` database using `MVVM` with `RxJava` pattern. `Fragment` asks `viewModel` for a data and `subscribes` withit. `ViewModel` gets data from local storage and returns to `Fragment` and meanwhile also sends request to server for updates. What happens is as follows:

- First Time `Fragment` will receive empty list i.e. first time DB is empty
- Meanwhile, `ViewModel` sends request to server and receives records and inserts in DB
- AS `Fragment` is subscribed to database, its `onSubscibe` event is called but with empty list

**MyFragment**

```
mySurveyViewModel.getAllMySurveys(surveyType)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe({

                    showMySurveysList(it)
                }, {
                })
```

**ViewModel**

```
fun getAllMySurveys(surveyType: Int): Flowable<List<MySurvey>> {
        updateMySurveysFromApi()
        return getMySurveysFromDatabase(surveyType)
    }

fun updateMySurveysFromApi() {
        mySurveyRepository.getSavedSurveysFromApi()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .flatMapIterable {
                    it.data
                }.map {
                    it.apply {
                        enumeratorId = AppPreferences.getString(Enumerator_Id, "")
                    }
                }.toList().observeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe({

                    Log.v("BaseDrawerActivity", "updateMySurveysFromApi: onSubscribe size ${it.size}")

                    insertMySurvey(it, true)

                }, {

                })
    }

fun insertMySurvey(surveys: List<MySurvey>, isSync: Boolean = false) {
        mySurveyRepository.saveSurveysInDb(surveys, isSync)
    }
```

**My Repository**

```
fun saveSurveysInDb(surveys: List<MySurvey>, isSync: Boolean) {
        if(isSync) {
            mySurveyDAO.insert(surveys)
        } else {
            Flowable.fromCallable { mySurveyDAO.insert(surveys) }
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .subscribe {
                    }
        }
    }
```

> Can anybody suggests what is the missing part? Why I am getting empty
>   list after insertion?

Comment: The problem here is probably because `mySurveyRepository.getSavedSurveysFromApi()` returns a `Flowable` that never completes, making `.toList()` operator waiting forever for upstream to complete. Remove `.flatMapIterable` and `.toList`, and put your iteration logic in `.map`.

Comment: @SanlokLee This worked for me. Please post as Answer, I will accept it. Thanks.